# How to resolve CS1503 with custom Converter

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, types

I have the following class/type in c# which I need to use to get something like a Point but with different function.

```
[TypeConverter(typeof(KnotenConverter))]
class Knoten
{
    int x, y;
    List<Knoten> neighbors;


    #region gettersetter
    //Standard getter and setter here

    #endregion

    public bool hasNeighbors()
    {
        return Neighbors.Count > 0;
    }

    class KnotenConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
        {
            if (destinationType == typeof(Point)) return true;
            return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
        }

        public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
        {
            Knoten from = (Knoten)value;
            if (destinationType == typeof(Point))
            {
                return new Point(from.X, from.Y);
            }
            return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
        }

    }
```

For using Knoten as a Point I implemented my own TypeConverter so to convert Knoten into Point. But I keep getting

> CS1503 Argument '2' cannot convert from GridCalcer.Knoten to System.Drawing.Point.

What did I do wrong and how can i solve this Error so that it can convert my Knoten into a Point "by itself"?

Comment: At which line do you get error? Is it a line in converter? Which line? Or is it occurs when setting value in e.g. `PropertyGrid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeConverter`s has nothing in common with compile time. The compiler error indicates that you are trying to pass `Knoten` instance to a method that expects `Point`. In order to be able to do that, you need to declare an [implicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversion operator:

```
class Knoten
{
    // ...

    public static implicit operator Point(Knoten source)
    {
        return new Point(source.X, source.Y);
    }
}
```